# How to show the two lines of heading and data without using table?

Tags: html, css

I've a following HTML code:

```
  <div><span class='top'>Answered</span></div><div id="hour">15</div>
  <div><span class='top'>Not Answered</span></div><div id="minute">35</div>
  <div><span class='top'>Marked for Review</span></div><div id="second">10</div>
  <div class='clear'></div>
```

The output of above code is displayed as below:

```
Answered
15
Not Answered
35
Marked for Review
10
```

Can anyone help me to bring the above data in following format? I can't use a `<table>` tag for this manipulation.

```
Answered  Not Answered  Marked for Review
   15          35               10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to wrap all of your top-bottom pairs in a div:

```
<div class="outer">
    <span class='top'>Answered</span>
    <div class="bottom" id="hour">15</div>
</div>
<div class="outer">
    <span class='top'>Not Answered</span>

    <div class="bottom" id="minute">35</div>
</div>
<div class="outer">
    <span class='top'>Marked for Review</span>
    <div class="bottom" id="second">10</div>
</div>
<div class='clear'></div>
```

Then float the outer divs to the left, and give them a center alignment:

```
.outer {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 5px;
}
.clear
{
    clear: both;
}
```

Working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6947c/